# Facebook API: how to show 'add-to-page' dialog box inside the canvas app

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I want to give ability to users to add the application in their fan pages directly from the canvas application.

Earlier there was a method (`fb:add-to-profile`) for adding application in user's profile tab, but now its no longer supported by facebook.

So, I am looking for similar kind of things for fan pages, either by using FBML or programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

There are new Graph API methods that let you programatically add tabs to pages.

See the 'tabs' connections here:

- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.